# Windows how to share mfc-7360n printer to Raspberry Pi 3 with cups

Tags: connection, windows

Brother MFC-7360N printer connected via USB to Windows 10 computer.
Both Windows and Raspberry Pi are on the same local network.
Raspberry Pi needs to be able to print to this printer.
Followed [these instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/169679/how-to-add-a-printer-to-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-computer/) as far as I could.

Specifically, when I pointed the Windows PC browser to `https://192.168.0.100:631` and clicked "Add Printer", the desired MFC-7360N printer was not an available option. (but it was in the tutorial)

Comment: Do you ask how to manage a printer on MS Window$? If so, this is not the right site for asking this.

Comment: No, I ask how to get the Pi to detect the printer, connected to the windows PC.